# Equi spaced grid lines in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a plot with major and minor ticks as well as major and minor grid lines. I would like the grid lines to be equi-spaced, but with the code below, the grid lines are not equi-spaced. How can I fix it?

```
mnt = MonthLocator(range(1, 13), bymonthday=1, interval=2)
mnt_fmt = DateFormatter("%b '%y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mnt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mnt_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MaxNLocator(20))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MaxNLocator(20))
# Create nice-looking grid for ease of visualization
ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)
ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
```

EDIT
[image]

Comment: Are you asking why the major tick increment is different on the x-axis vs the y-axis?  If so, it's because you're locating every month (30 units, due to the way mpl handles dates) on the x-axis, but every 20 units on the y-axis.  However, if you're asking why 20 units on the y-axis is a different physical size than 20 units on the x-axis, it's because the aspect ratio of the plot isn't set.  Use `ax.set(aspect=1)` or `ax.axis('equal')` to set it to 1, if you're wanting perfect squares for the grid.

Comment: thanks @JoeKington, added a pic of what I am seeing. The minor ticks on x-axis are not equi-spaced w.r.t major ticks. e.g. between may and july 2014, the distance between the major tick for may 2014 and minor tick is different than the distance between the major tick for july 2014 and the minor tick precedding it

Comment: also @JoeKington, wouldn't setting `ax.axis('equal')` to 1, not make the plot a square one? Some of my plots are rectangular

Comment: `axis('equal')` sets the aspect to 1.  It doesn't directly control the shape of the plot (and by default, it won't have any effect on the shape at all -- only when the `adjustable` parameter of the axis is set to `box`).  The aspect ratio in a matplotlib axes is the ratio of the y-scale to the x-scale in data coordinates. It's not the aspect ratio of the "box" surrounding the axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing on the x-axis is effectively the difference between marking the first of every month and marking every "x" number of days.

You've set the major ticks to be located at the first of every month.  However, you've set the minor ticks to be located every 5 days.

Because the first of every month is not evenly spaced, the major ticks won't be evenly spaced.  However, the minor ticks will always be 5 days apart.  Therefore, you'll see a variation in the relative spacing of the major and minor ticks on the x-axis.

In the end, you'll have to decide which one you want more: Ticks at the first of every month, or ticks on a regular interval.  You can't have both, unfortunately.